# jQuery removes wrapping element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading a html file with jquery $.get and wrap the response. But jQuery removes my wrapper .

I made the following example which demonstrates my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/pwm76bp6/

Everyone who dont want to open the link here is the example code:

```
alert($('<div><div>Hallo</div></div>').html());
```

I would expect that the whole string should be alerted. Whats the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Comment: Why not `alert('<div><div>Hallo</div></div>');`. And, if you need insert that HMTL: `document.getElementById('receptor_id').innerHTML = '<div><div>Hallo</div></div>';`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read `outerHTML` property.

```js
console.log($('<div><div>Hallo</div></div>').prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically wrap it with an element, then get the html() of the wrapped element.

```
alert($('<div><div>Hallo</div></div>').wrap("<div></div>").parent().html());
```

Comment: i think he needs to know why it didnt work in his :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't *remove* your wrapper. jQuery `html()` does return the `contents` of an element.

When you do `$('<div>my content</div>')` you creating an element, *then* you get the inner html with `html()` which is then alerted in your example.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you will get the `html` of your outer element `<div>`. And the content of the outer `<div>` is `<div>Hallo</div>`.

You can do what you want with a default property:

```
alert($('<div><div>Hallo</div></div>')[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

the function "html" does return the html content of a given element. In your case "html()" returns the content of the outer div, which excludes the outer itself.

You may can overcome this by wrapping your html like:

```
var html = '<div><div>Hallo</div></div>';
var outerHtml = $(html).wrap('<div />').parent().html();
```

hope this helps.